# What should be the PFQuery to fetch record for column type "array" at parse?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am having a column ID with type `Array`
eg.

```
ID - ["1","3","5"]
    ID - ["2","3"]
    ID - ["9","6","3"]
```

at parse database

Now I want to fetch those records where ID is contained with "3"

```
 [getData whereKey:@"ID" matchesRegex:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",intIndexPathM+1]];
```

This return empty array as well as not giving any error to recognize

I search on [parse document](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#queries/iOS) also but i didn't get any clue for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the docs there is a section for query on array values:

```
// Find objects where the array in arrayKey contains 2.
[query whereKey:@"arrayKey" equalTo:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2]];
```

Comment: It is returning empty array as here @"arrayKey" is Array type column with values like ["3","2"] and i want only those records where @"arrayKey" value contains 3

Comment: @Roshni I don't understand. Can you include in your question the expected result?

Comment: I was confused about how parse would check for contained query with "equalTo" identifier but anyways it worked with combination of Array Column type and "equalTo" filteration

Comment: Can you edit your answer to show how you did this? I'm stuck on figuring out how to query to find a string contained in an array. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious whether you're trying to solve the right problem the wrong way. If ID is a the objectId of another parse object, then you don't need to be using strings or regular expressions. You can save one object inside another and Parse will automatically handle the references to the foreign objects. This will also let you use the `includeKey:` method in PFQuery to download the parent and child object in one operation. To ask if an array field contains a scalar, you can still use the `whereKey:equalTo:` method; Parse will just do the right thing.

That does not apply for regular expressions, however. I'm nervous why you want a regular expression. It's not possible to index a regular expression, so your query can never be efficient and you'll run into scaling issues which Parse won't be able to bail you out of quite quickly. Are you really trying to find all object where any element in an array field contains any string where any character is "3"? If so, why? We should probably come up with a more efficient solution if that's the case.

Comment: In your answer you have talk about `includeKey:` how can i use that for child table? I have ask the question regarding that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17228542/join-two-tables-using-parse you might help me. Please check out.

Comment: You should listen to the existing answer by lxt; The problem is you're ignoring the built-in methods for representing relationships (just setting one object as a child of another).