# Join two tables using parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I have one database at parse.com

Where I have one class called `UserDetail`

In that class I have one array Field called `occupationid`

For this column i have another class Called `Occupation` where columns are like
`occupationid`, `occupationname`

Now I want to fetch all data from `UserDetail` as well as all data from `occupation` class according to the `occupationid` stored in `UserDetail`

---

`UserDetail`

Username        -       occupationid      -        Detail

Jhon           -         ["1","3","4"]     -       ajfdkaldjlajsdkfjaldkf

---

`Occupation`

occupationid     -   occupation

1        -           accountant

2         -          lawyer

3          -         painter

4         -          writer

like wise.

I have gone through the document and about `PFRelation` i read but didn't get how to apply that in my case to fetch this kind of data.

Also i have tried with

```
    PFQuery *getuserdetail = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"UserDetail"];

    [getuserdetail orderByAscending:@"celebid"];

    PFQuery *getoccupation = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Occupation"];
    [getoccupation whereKey:@"occupationid" matchesKey:@"occupationid" inQuery:getuserdetail];
```

Any suggestions? I have to do the same for other 2,3 columns.
Any help will be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Data is adding at the parse.com DataBrowser directly and not from the code.

I created one column with type `Relation` in `UserDetail` class
Which ask me to add `occupationid` and `occupation`

When i added that i face two problems

1> When I try to add the same occupationid for different user it is creating two rows for the same `occupationid`. It means for two user having same occupation it is creating two rows in `occupationtable`
eg.
objectid - occupationid   - occupation
adfk12   -  1     -      School teacher
jdlkfg56  -  1     -      School teacher

2> When I tried to fetch from the code it is giving me errors

```
PFQuery *getuserdetail = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"UserDetail"];        
[getuserdetail orderByAscending:@"celebid"];
[getuserdetail includeKey:@"occupation"];
[getuserdetail whereKey:@"userid" equalTo:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",intuserID]];
```

**occupationid = "(<00000000>.(null) -> Occupation)";**

where `Occupation` is the class name
`occupation` is the column name.
I tried with editing column name `occupation` with `occupationname` if it is getting ambiguity. But that also not working.

Comment: as ixt explains ... IN a word, if you have table "posts" and one of the columns "author" is a **POINTER** to another table "users": simply includeKey("author"), and that will bring down THE WHOLE AUTHOR OBJECT for each line of the result.  then, with that object you have everything (!) in the users table for that author.  simply then use objectForKey as usual, on that object from "author" column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're getting a bit unstuck because you're thinking of Parse in terms of a 'normal' SQL-like database. I say this because from what you've written, it looks as if your `occupationid` field is redundant (because Parse automatically assigns all objects a unique ID). You can use `PFRelation` to associate an occupation with a user, like so:

`[someUser setObject:someOccupation forKey:@"occupation"]`

This will set a pointer on `someUser`, under the key `occupation`.

However, as you might have found out (and maybe why you're not sure how to apply `PFRelation` properly) is that *by default* Parse doesn't fetch related objects when querying. You need to explicitly tell Parse to do this.

To do this, you use the `includeKey:` method. So, to query for a user *and* get their occupation at the same time (assuming you've set the occupation as a `PFRelation`), you can do this:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"UserDetail"];
[query includeKey:@"occupation"];
[query findObjectsInBackground... etc
```

My best advice would be to try not to think of Parse like MySQL or similar, since it works in a rather different way. I find Parse's documentation to be really useful and clear, so perhaps it might be worth looking there also.

Comment: I am not adding data from the code so that i add PFRelation from code.I have to make a column with PFRelation at DataBrowser at parse.com which shows me option as "View Relations". In that case how do i add " ["1","3","4"] " kind of data in my `Occupationid` column?

Comment: Till now I have `Occupationid` column as array type in `UserDetail` class.Which i want to join with the `Occupation` class' `Occupationid` column to find the related occupations for that user

Comment: You can have an array of `PFRelations` - you just create a key with an array type, and then populate it with `PFRelation` objects. Again, try not to think of Parse as a database, but as an ORM.

Comment: Hi @lxt can you explain how to add an object to the pointer type in parse table.I am having the functionality of posting a image users can  able to like the particular post.So while getting the list of posts has been created i need no of likes at a time.so Please help me how to Design a Table.@lxt